# How to display a Chinese title while using TeX in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I was going to draw a subplot like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
y1 = np.sin(x)
y2 = np.cos(x)
y3 = np.sin(pow(x,2))
plt.rc('font',size = 16,family = 'Simhei')
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus'] = False
plt.rc('text',usetex = True)

pic1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
pic1.plot(x,y1,'r--',label = '$\sin{x}$'); pic1.legend()
pic1.set_title('第一个图像')

pic2 = plt.subplot(2,2,2)
pic2.plot(x,y2,'k--',label = '$\cos{x}$') ; pic2.legend()
pic2.set_title('第二个图像')

pic3 = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
pic3.plot(x,y3,'r--',label = '$\sin{(x^2)}$') ; pic3.legend()
pic3.set_title('第三个图像')
plt.show()
```

but it returns an error like this:

```
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cm-super/type1ec.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmr.fd))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/underscore/underscore.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file b09c0b82eaeea985330356c98a53236d.aux.
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 第 (U+7B2C)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.29 {\rmfamily 第
                   $1$个图像}%
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmpntafuhs9/b09c0b82eaeea985330356c98a53236d.log.
```

In LaTeX I know that I can use `\usepackage{ctex}` to solve this problem, but I cant handle it in matplotlib. I turned the title into English and it works. but I need a Chinese title using TeX.

Comment: This answer shows how you can add your own preamble including `\usepackage` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49958454/765091. If you follow that technique and include `\usepackage{ctex}`, does it help?

Comment: It helps : ) . I added `\usepackage{ctex}` . The program dont return the error now and it returns a picture with 3 subplots, however there is only blank space where the Chinese title should be. I guess the problem goes from the complier. Could you please tell me how to change the LaTeX complier to XeLaTeX?

Comment: This what matplotlib recommends for XeLaTeX: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/pgf.html There's a section in that page for "Custom Preamble", so you should be able to include your package there.

Comment: @slothrop Maybe post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as using the `ctex` package as highlighted in the question, making this work needs a flavour of LaTeX with better Unicode support than pdfLaTeX: ideally XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Matplotlib lets you do this using the [pgf backend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/pgf.html).

The documentation covers the various configuration options that should be added to `plt.rcParams`: the key ones are:

- `pgf.texsystem`: specify `xelatex` (the default), `lualatex` or `pdflatex`
- `pgf.preamble`: specify a custom preamble for the LaTeX document to be produced. This can include `\usepackage` statements, so `ctex` or any other relevant packages can be used.